# Centering a text output div inside a wrapper-div

Tags: html, css, text, css-position, center

I have a div called note, which inside has textWrapper and noteText. I need for the text to drop a line when reaches the limit (width), but for some reason it just cuts the sentence, no dropping line and no scroll as intended. code attached:

any ideas?

```
.note {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("media/notebg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    
}

/*Styles for text in the note*/
.note > .noteText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.note > .textWrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) to automatically break your text.

```css
.note {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("media/notebg.png");
    background-color: burlywood;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/*Styles for text in the note*/
.note>.noteText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.note>.textWrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="note">
        <div class="textWrap">
            <div class="noteText">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta inventore vero ex quibusdam porro necessitatibus accusantium architecto? Delectus, officiis. Magni natus pariatur aliquam delectus excepturi quod ipsa! Natus, ipsa tempore.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```